How to access a file hyperlinked in a webpage
How can I access a .dat file from a website that needs authentication using python. I'm able to get to the to the website and can verify that that file is there but I can't download it with python. Usually I would go the website, click on the name of the file and it would download directly to my download folder.
import requests

# Connect to the gateway server
username = 'user'
password = 'pass'

# Specify the remote file to download
url = 'location/of/website'
filename = 'data_file_of_interest.dat'
r = requests.get(url, auth=(username,password),allow_redirects=True)
open(filename, 'wb')

<_io.BufferedWriter name='data_file_of_interest.dat'>

After opening a blank file you have to save to it right? same:
so do:
...
r = requests.get(url,allow_redirects=True)
with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(r.content)

you can make sure to catch up errors with:
...
if r.status_code == 200:
    with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
                file.write(r.content)
else:
    print("request not succesful")


Thank you, I've actually tried this method before and the r.content is an <!doctype html>. However, I know the data should be separated by commas. I think the r.content that is being written is the html file for the webpage but I need the .dat file on that webpage. I hope this makes my question more clear. Thank you for your (and others) help in advance!

I have tested this with url https://wikimediafoundation.org/wp-content/themes/shiro/assets/src/svg/logo-horizontal.svg and so it should work for another url that ends with .dat as well i think, i can debug it further only if you provide the .dat url i think .dat url is not file as you said but a web page that downloads a file, you can check this by using browser and copying download link, the link which is used to download will be different, i am not sure how to proceed with this without knowing your .dat web link

But FIRST make sure the url you have tried ends with .dat, that is, url='location/of/website/data_file_of_interest.dat'

Ok let me try to explain another way (I am still a python noob so bare with me). 1) when url = 'location/of/website/' --> request successful. 2) when url = 'location/of/website/data_file_of_interest.dat' --> request not successful. 3) the 'data_file_of_interest.dat' is a hyperlink on the url that downloads that data once clicked.

is the url you are using when pasted on browser downloads file automatically? only then my answer works, if not what is required by user to do after pasting url in browser to download file?
